# CCC'2020 J5/S2 Escape Room Solution (Python)

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to solve the J5/S2 Escape Room Problem from the CCC'2020. I can't figure out why the recursion does not stop at a return statement.

Here is the link to the problems:
https://cemc.uwaterloo.ca/contests/computing/2020/ccc/juniorEF.pdf

```
def find_route(start_num, grid, visited=[]):
    factors = []
    result = 'no'
    for num in range(1, start_num + 1):
        if start_num % num == 0:
            paired_factor = int(start_num/num)
            if num <= len(grid) and paired_factor <= len(grid[0]):
                factors.append((int(num), paired_factor))
    print('xxxx', factors, start_num)

    for m, n in factors:
        x = m - 1
        y = n - 1
        if m == len(grid) and n == len(grid[0]):
            return 'yes'
            raise SystemExit(0)
        else:
            if (x, y) in visited:
                continue
            else:
                visited.append((x, y))
                start_num = grid[x][y]
                find_route(start_num, grid, visited=visited)
        print('why continue')
    return result



def main():
    grid = [[3, 10, 8, 14],
            [1, 11, 12, 12],
            [6, 2, 3, 9]]
    start_num = grid[0][0]
    result = find_route(start_num, grid)
    print(result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return your recursion.

This is the relevant snippet:

```
            else:
                visited.append((x, y))
                start_num = grid[x][y]
>               return find_route(start_num, grid, visited=visited)
```

Personally I would consider starting from the end, as it would be more deterministic to find the right product than the right factors.